# MongoDB - Use field value for $centerSphere coordinate input? [subquery equivalant?]

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial, database, nosql

Got a database of places and their corresponding coordinates.
I want to get all the places that are nearby a given place, and centerSphere does this beautifully.

Problem is I can only get this to work by hardcoding the long/lat coordinates, instead of using something like a subquery result.
Where I'd query the long/lat values of a place knowing the specific ID like:

```
db.places.find(
   {_id: '9'},
   {_id:0, coordinates:1}
)
```

and get a set of coordinates back like:

```
[-20.32, 89.02]
```

Right now it this works:

```
{ $geoWithin:
    {$centerSphere: [ [ -20.32, 89.02 ] , 100 / 3960 ] }
}
```

I'm looking for something more like:

```
X = db.places.find(    {_id: '9'},       {_id:0, coordinates:1} )
{ $geoWithin:
    {$centerSphere: [ X , 100 / 3960 ] }
}
```

[not literally, just thought ^^ was the most clear way to represent what I'm trying to do]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you want to fetch 'places' near one where the _id is known (but the lat, lon is not)

one easy option is a 2-step find. i would do `findOne()` since you use _id as the query

```
result = db.places.findOne( {_id: '9'}, {_id:0, coordinates:1} )
lonlat = result.coordinates

db.places.find( { $geoWithin:
    {$centerSphere: [ lonlat , 100 / 3960 ] }
})
```

a second option is a custom [map-reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/) [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/). i have no experience with these aggregations but imagine its straightforward.

mongo's aggregation pipeline is fantastic and it would be nice to run an aggregation thru the pipeline and pass the value of 'coordinates' using a temporary variable.

```
db.places.aggregate( [{ $match: {"_id" : 9}} , 
{ $project: { "lonlat":  "$coordinates"}} , 
{ $geoNear: { near : { coordinates: "$lonlat"}, 
maxDistance: 1000, spherical: true, distanceField: "dist.calculated", } }])
```

BUT $geoNear has to be first stage in an aggregate. and your case requires a match stage for _id; so not possible. further it appears your coordinates are not in [2dsphere](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) geojson format.

Update---
Note that one can use javascript in the shell including variables (var).

```
var result = db.places.findOne( {_id: '9'}, {_id:0, coordinates:1} );
print(result);
printjson(result);
printjson(result[0]);
```